# mocking a function inside a function and getting calls count in jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

Considering this module in `script.js`:

```
const randomizeRange = (min, max) => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
};

const randomArr = (n, min, max) => {
  const arr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    arr.push(randomizeRange(min, max));
  }
  return arr;
};


module.exports = { randomArr, randomizeRange };
```

In the test file below, shouldn't the call count of `randomizeRangeMock` be 100 because it is being called inside `randomArrMock` which is called once? Why do I get 0

```
const randomArr = require("./script").randomArr;
const randomizeRange = require("./script").randomizeRange;

const randomArrMock = jest.fn(randomArr);
const randomizeRangeMock = jest.fn(randomizeRange);

test("tests for randomArr", () => {
  expect(randomArrMock(100, 20, 1000)).toHaveLength(100);
  expect(randomArrMock.mock.calls.length).toBe(1)
  expect(randomizeRangeMock.mock.calls.length).toBe(100) //This fails because its 0
});
```

Comment: Can I ask why you are even mocking these functions at all considering they are pretty straightforward JavaScript methods and not connecting to any back end API's or databases?

Comment: It's jut for purposes of learning how JEST works, its an example

Comment: I didn't mean this in a negative manner mate. I was just curious and asked a genuine question about why you wanted to mock a function which used pretty straightforward JS code and wasn't making any complex back end calls. Just asked for my own clarity!

Comment: Apologies @AJC24, I misunderstood!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I appreciate that you are trying to just understand `jest` with this question and so I will answer as best I can. I'd normally recommend that you don't mock functions unless you are making some kind of complex back end call to a server or database or whatever. The more real testing you can do with real code (and not mocks) is infinitely more beneficial. That would be my tip for you going forward.

But for the purpose of this question - here's what's going on.

The reason you're not seeing your mocks work in the right way here is because you've essentially created two **separate** mocks:

- You've created a single mock for `randomizeArr`.
- You've created another single, separate mock for `randomizeRange`.

When you invoke `randomArrMock(100, 20, 1000)` in your test, this will invoke your single mock for `randomizeArr` as you've designated but that mock has absolutely no concept of the other mock for `randomizeRange` ever existing. And so it's never invoked behind the scenes. So this is why you see a `0` for the amount of calls at the end.

It's just a matter of changing your setup a little bit here to designate which mocks are invoked and when in order to see both work together as you're expecting.

What I would actually choose here is **not** to mock your `randomizeRange` method at all. That method invoked `Math.floor` and that's going to be much easier to "spy on" (which is a hint for the method we're going to use here) in this case. That `Math.floor` method is invoked once with each call to `randomizeRange` and so it will be an ideal choice. It should also be called `100` times, the same as your method.

The reason we're choosing to `spyOn` the method rather than to use an actual mock in the way you have done already is because we want to keep the original behaviour and so spying on how many times the method is called without overwriting the intended behaviour is ideal.

So keep your existing mock for `randomizeArr` as follows:

```
const randomArrMock = jest.fn(randomArr);
```

Now set up the spy for `Math.floor`

```
const mathFloorSpy = jest.spyOn(Math.prototype, `floor`);
```

This "spy" will effectively spy on this method without overwriting its behaviour. You **can** overwrite the behaviour if you want to but we want to keep the behaviour intact while just counting how many times it is called.

So now when you run your test suite:

```
test("tests for randomArr", () => {
  expect(randomArrMock(100, 20, 1000)).toHaveLength(100);
  expect(randomArrMock.mock.calls.length).toBe(1)
  expect(mathFloorSpy.mock.calls.length).toBe(100)
});
```

This will now pass as `Math.floor` will have been invoked each time your `randomizeRange` method was called.

Finally don't forget to restore the original `Math.floor` functionality when your test is finished by using:

```
mathFloorSpy.mockRestore();
```

Happy testing!

Comment: One question, why do I have to call `mockRestore()` if I have not changed the implementation?

Comment: Truthfully you won't need it in this case but it's just habit on my part to always tear down all mocks I've set up in a test. It's a good habit to get into. I've had cases where mocks have conflicted with each other so it's always best to tear them down afterwards to make sure that doesn't happen.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a common question, and the most "official" solution I can find was on the Jest GitHub issues page, at https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/936#issuecomment-545080082.

Since you are using `require` instead of ES modules transpiled with babel, the solutions described in that linked issue don't seem to apply as well.

I would modify your `script.js` module to directly reference the exports used, so that the mocks refer to the correct function:

```js
exports.randomizeRange = (min, max) => {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
};

exports.randomArr = (n, min, max) => {
    const arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arr.push(exports.randomizeRange(min, max));
    }
    return arr;
};
```

And then your test implementation would reference the mocked functions:

```js
const myScript = require('../script');

jest.spyOn(myScript, 'randomArr');
jest.spyOn(myScript, 'randomizeRange');

test("tests for randomArr", () => {
    expect(myScript.randomArr(100, 20, 1000)).toHaveLength(100);
    expect(myScript.randomArr).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(myScript.randomizeRange).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(100);
});
```

Using [`spyOn`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname) and [`toHaveBeenCalledTimes`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tohavebeencalledtimesnumber) improves readability here.

---

Now, giving me own piece of advice: Write testable code. If your code is testable, well, you can easily write tests for it, and testable code is generally more modular and flexible; but don't focus on testing implementation details.

In your example, if you want to expose a `randomArr` method, then don't also expose `randomizeRange`; your `randomArr` method can call `randomizeRange`, but that is an implementation detail you shouldn't worry about.

If you want to make your `randomArr` much easier to test, consider making the range method (or the range) a parameter. You can then test it without testing some implementation of how it generates random ranges. Something like this:

```js
exports.randomArr = (n, min, max, randomRangeGenerator) => {
    const arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arr.push(randomRangeGenerator(min, max));
    }
    return arr;
};
```

You can extend this pattern to `randomizeRange` as well. For testing that method, either pass in the `floor` and `random` functions as parameters, or mock them (through the Math object) in your tests. Working with `Math.random` in tests is difficult since it will produce different values on each run, so it's important mock that.